# "Come to life" vs. "come alive"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, predicate

I've heard both phrases used but would love to learn what the difference is and if one is more proper than the other.

E.g.

> The green paint really made it come [to life/alive].

Comment: They mean two different things.

Comment: @HotLicks care to elaborate? lol

Comment: For people in the United States old enough to have been bombarded by TV commercials during the 1960s, the phrase "come alive" is probably ineradicably associated with a repellent but memorable Pepsi-Cola ad campaign: "Come alive! Come alive! You're in the Pepsi generation!" The jingle was especially awful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most contexts they're equivalent and interchangeable. But imho ***come alive*** is somewhat more likely to be used figuratively, and ***come to life*** is more likely to be a literal usage. Thus...

> *The atmosphere in the cinema [**came alive**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22atmosphere%20came%20alive%22) when Frankenstein's monster [**came to life**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22frankenstein%27s%20monster%20came%20to%20life%22)*
>    is far more likely than
>   *The atmosphere in the cinema [**came to life**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=MEeZW4eEFYiy0gXa3IPYBA&q=%22frankenstein%27s%20monster%20came%20alive%22&oq=%22frankenstein%27s%20monster%20came%20alive%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...417365.420990.0.421306.12.12.0.0.0.0.574.1747.0j4j2j5-1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.1.193...33i10k1.0.KLuaaGzL9OQ) when Frankenstein's monster [**came alive**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=ZUiZW5OMBNLRwQKBkrWwAw&q=%22atmosphere%20came%20to%20life%22&oq=%22atmosphere%20came%20to%20life%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...150287.154569.0.154960.12.12.0.0.0.0.328.1862.0j8j1j1.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.9YVXI2TUGAE)*

That's 116+93=**209** hits in Google Books for the two usages in the first example, and 4+77=**81** hits for those in what I consider to be the "less idiomatic" second example.